# Use result of multiple rows to do arithmetic operation

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a query to multiply the count that I receive from subquery to fees amount, But I don't know how to do that. Any help/suggestion?
**Oracle query is:**

```
select courseid,coursename,fees*tmp 
from course c join registration r on 
r.courseid=c.courseid 
and tmp IN (select count(*) 
from course c join registration r on 
r.courseid=c.courseid group by coursename);
```

I tried to use like a variable tmp ,But i don't think it works in oracle query. Is there an alternative way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, because you can only select data from tables that appeared between FROM and WHERE. The IN operator is a quick way to save having to write a bunch of OR statements, it is not something that can establish a variable in the outer query.

Instead do something like:

```
select courseid,coursename,fees * COUNT(r.courseID) OVER(PARTITION BY c.coursename)
from course c join registration r on 
r.courseid=c.courseid
```

Edit/update: you noted that this query produces too many rows and you only want to see distinct course names. In that case it would be better to just use the registrations table to count the number of people on the course and then multiply the fees:

```
SELECT
  c.courseid, c.coursename, c.fees * COALESCE(r.numberOfstudents, 0) as courseWorth
FROM
  course c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (select courseid, COUNT(*) as numberofstudents FROM registration GROUP BY courseid) r
  ON c.courseID = r.courseid
```

Comment: It works.. But let's say there are multiple same course name but I only want rows with distinct names.. how can i achieve that?

Comment: That's a more classic grouping query. I'll edit my answer to include an example

Comment: I don't have the right to complain as I'm the one requesting for help. BTW thanks it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, sorry - i didn't mean complain in the negative sense, but it's a nuance of english that is hard to pick up for non native speakers/over internet. I reworded my answer, glad we could help. Keep the COUNT() OVER... version in mind - it would be handy for example to have a mix of detail lines "who are all the students that are on the course" togetehr with a totals column where every row has a same value indicating 100 students or $10000 dollars worth of course.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing function like Caius or you can use a join like this:

```
 select courseid,coursename, fees * COALESCE(sub.cnt,0) 
 from course c 
 join registration r on r.courseid=c.courseid 
 left join  (
   select coursename, count(*) as cnt
   from course c2 
   join registration r2 on r2.courseid=c2.courseid 
   group by coursename
 ) as sub;
```

> note: I make no claim your joins are correct -- I'm basing this query off of your example not on any knowledge of your data model.

Comment: I forgot one thing - the reuse of r and c for aliases both inside and outside the main query; will that cause oracle to get confused about the subquery being coordinated or no?

Comment: it works fine, It's just that I wasn't able to do arithmetic operation.

Comment: @dikshamsc -- did you use both your fingers and your toes to count on? :)

Comment: @dikshamsc -- it was a joke.